# Group Pandas DataFrame in Time Interval and Plot

Tags: python, pandas, list, plot

## Goal

**Group a pandas dataframe in 30s intervals and extract the data to plot it.**

## Example

```
import pandas as pd

log = [
        ['2022/10/10_6:13:39', '6328f0c6ad70889fd28dcd07'],
        ['2022/10/10_6:13:49', '6328f0c6ad70889fd28dcd07'],
        ['2022/10/10_6:14:23', '6328f0c6ad70889fd28dcd07'],
        ['2022/10/10_6:14:25', '6328b959a5745f6fa5206fa6'],
        ['2022/10/10_6:15:4', '6328b959a5745f6fa5206fa6'],
        ['2022/10/10_6:15:52', '628fa4ac88be7ffeb9b7e7e3']]

df = pd.DataFrame(log,
                 columns=['timestamp', 'data'])

# convert to timestamp format
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],format='%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S')
```

The dataframe:

```
            timestamp                      data
0 2022-10-10 06:13:39  6328f0c6ad70889fd28dcd07
1 2022-10-10 06:13:49  6328f0c6ad70889fd28dcd07
2 2022-10-10 06:14:23  6328f0c6ad70889fd28dcd07
3 2022-10-10 06:14:25  6328b959a5745f6fa5206fa6
4 2022-10-10 06:15:04  6328b959a5745f6fa5206fa6
5 2022-10-10 06:15:52  628fa4ac88be7ffeb9b7e7e3
```

## My approach

```
# Group in intervals 
g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp',freq='30s'))
```

## The issue

1. I would like to see the grouped dataframe. How do I do that?
2. I would like to plot how many unique data there was within each interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use group by you need an aggregation function in your case if you want the number of values you can use `count()`. To check the data grouped you can use list. Then you can just plot the data using a bar plot

```py
grouped_data = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp',freq='30s')).agg(list)

grouped_counts = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp',freq='30s')).count()
grouped_counts.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

**EDIT** for unique values

if you want unique values, you can aggregate by a set and count the values

```
grouped_data = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp',freq='30s')).agg(set)
grouped_data['counts'] = grouped_data['data'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
grouped_data.plot(y='counts', kind='bar')
```